# My program unfortunately stops when the send mail button is clicked. I have added the the three jar files and the permission for internet

Tags: java, android, api

I have been trying to send an email for sometime now using the java mail api for android.I have tried several codes on the internet but still keep getting the same error message when the apk is run on a mobile device which says "appName unfortunately stopped".I am new to android and i would be very happy if someone could help me on this platform.Also i am using android studio as my IDE. Thank you
Below is the code for my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rollxreuben.mailing.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="Send Mail"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the code for the java class

```
    package com.example.rollxreuben.mailing;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.mail.Authenticator;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
            private Button btn;
        Session session = null;
        ProgressDialog pDialog = null;
        Context context = null;
        String rec, receipt;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            context = this;
            btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.port","smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");

            session  = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("email@gmail.com","PASSWORD");
                }
            });

            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"","Sending Mail",true);
            SendMail sendMail = new SendMail();
            sendMail.execute();
        }
    }
```

SendMail class:

```
private class SendMail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("busben97@gmail.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("busben97@gmail.com"));
                message.setSubject("Testing Mail");
                message.setContent("Hello ","text/html; charset=utf-8");
                Transport.send(message);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }




}
```

Finally this is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.rollxreuben.mailing">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>

//This is the log file
07-05 17:00:37.129 4376-4376/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-05 17:00:37.129 4376-4376/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
07-05 17:00:38.381 4376-4376/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing-2/lib/x86
07-05 17:00:38.389 4376-4376/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-05 17:00:38.446 4376-4376/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-05 17:00:39.785 4376-4402/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-05 17:00:39.785 4376-4402/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
07-05 17:00:40.838 4376-4376/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
07-05 17:00:40.848 4376-4376/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing I/Choreographer: Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-05 17:00:44.293 4376-4376/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing I/Choreographer: Skipped 206 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-05 17:01:17.648 4376-4939/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing W/art: Verification of java.lang.String javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.encodeWord(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean) took 105.438ms
07-05 17:01:17.752 4376-4939/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing E/Exception: For input string: "smtp.gmail.com"
                                                                          java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "smtp.gmail.com"
                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                                                                              at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:398)
                                                                              at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
                                                                              at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
                                                                              at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
                                                                              at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
                                                                              at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
                                                                              at com.example.rollxreuben.mailing.MainActivity$SendMail.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:93)
                                                                              at com.example.rollxreuben.mailing.MainActivity$SendMail.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
07-05 17:01:18.733 4376-4376/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing I/Choreographer: Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-05 17:01:20.603 4376-4376/com.example.rollxreuben.mailing I/Choreographer: Skipped 111 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Please paste exception stack trace

Comment: add logcat , we're not wizards

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "smtp.gmail.com"

The error is caused by `parseInt()` for a non-numeric value `smtp.gmail.com`

this is caused by this line `props.put("mail.smtp.port","smtp.gmail.com");`

**port** should be a number you are passing a host address, either change the key `mail.smtp.port` or change the value `smtp.gmail.com`.

Comment: Thanks but when I changed the it to "mail.smtp.host" the program is not able to connect to the specified port.I tried port 888 as well but still the same response

Comment: @P.Rollx this is another question, if this answer solved your error, mark it as accepted and you can search/ask another question for the new issue. it could be common and you may find answers related to it

Comment: @P.Rollx yes it did, do you see that exception anymore ? NO so it solved the error mentioned in the question, do u see this exception anymore `Exception: For input string` NO .. so if you want to use this site, you have to use it correctly

Comment: Alright thanks it did solve that error just that the main reason i posted the question still persists.Nonetheless thank you